# Remove empty lines at the beginning and at the end of a List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Given a `List<string>` I need to **remove all the empty lines at the beginning and at the end of the list**.

NOTE: I consider an empty line a line that has no content, but may contain whitespaces and tabs. This is the method to check if a line is empty:

```
    private bool HasContent(string line)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            return false;

        foreach (char c in line)
        {
            if (c != ' ' && c != '\t')
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What efficient and readable code would you suggest to do that?

#### Confirmed example

```
[" ", " ", " ", " ", "A", "B", " ", "C", " ", "D", " ", " ", " "]
```

Such a list should be trimmed, by removing all empty lines at the beginning *and* the end to the following result:

```
["A", "B", " ", "C", " ", "D"]
```

Comment: Do you know about [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (.Net 4)?

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` consider tab as white space too!

Comment: You current code does remove any line that contains a whitespace or tab. Is that a feature?

Comment: @DanielPeñalba `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` treats tabs `\t` as whitespace. Your argument is invalid. `bool whiteSpace = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there is a built in method that checks this: [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

The answer ColinE provides does not meet the requirement since it removes all lines that are empty, not just at the beginning or end.

I think you need to build your own solution:

```
int start = 0, end = sourceList.Count - 1;

while (start < end && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceList[start])) start++;
while (end >= start && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceList[end])) end--;

return sourceList.Skip(start).Take(end - start + 1);
```

Comment: I think that sould be `sourceList.Skip(start).Take(end - start + 1);` right?

Comment: Also, the second check should be `end >= start`, I edited the answer.

Comment: Consider using `int first = sourceList.FindIndex(HasContent)` and `int last = sourceList.FindLastIndex(HasContent)` where `HasContent` is the method from the original question. It's cleaner than the `while` loops. You can also use a lambda, of course, as in `sourceList.FindIndex(s => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var results = textLines1.SkipWhile(e => !HasContent(e))
                        .Reverse()
                        .SkipWhile(e => !HasContent(e))
                        .Reverse()
                        .ToList();
```

How it works? Skips all empty lines at from of the list, reverse it and do the same (what actually skips all empty lines from back of the list). After another reverse you're getting proper results in right order.

If list is really huge you can consider using standard `while` loops and list indexing because of performance considerations, but for normal data impart of reversion shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I got there eventually ;-)

Comment: Seems too expensive to reverse the list twice.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq, you could perform the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> list  = sourceList.SkipWhile(source => !HasContent(source))
                                      .TakeWhile(source => HasContent(source));
```

This 'skips' strings until it finds one with content, then 'takes' all the strings until one without content is found.

Although as @MarcinJuraszek points out, this will stop after the first line that does not have content, rather than removing those at the end of the list.

To do that, you could use the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> list  = sourceList.SkipWhile(source => !HasContent(source))
                                      .Reverse()
                                      .SkipWhile(source => !HasContent(source))
                                      .Reverse();
```

A little bit convoluted, but should do the trick.

Comment: Wrong! Will stop on first empty line after any with content!

Comment: Missing the closing bracket again ^^ (of SkipWhile and TakeWhile).

Answer (score 2):

Check this extension method I did just now:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<string> TrimList(this List<string> list)
    {
        int listCount = list.Count;
        List<string> listCopy = list.ToList();
        List<string> result = list.ToList();

        // This will encapsulate removing an item and the condition to remove it.
        // If it removes the whole item at some index, it return TRUE.
        Func<int, bool> RemoveItemAt = index =>
        {
            bool removed = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listCopy[index]) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listCopy[index]))
            {
                result.Remove(result.First(item => item == listCopy[index]));
                removed = true;
            }

            return removed;
        };

        // This will encapsulate the iteration over the list and the search of 
        // empty strings in the given list
        Action RemoveWhiteSpaceItems = () =>
        {
            int listIndex = 0;

            while (listIndex < listCount && RemoveItemAt(listIndex))
            {
                listIndex++;
            }
        };

        // Removing the empty lines at the beginning of the list
        RemoveWhiteSpaceItems();

        // Now reversing the list in order to remove the 
        // empty lines at the end of the given list
        listCopy.Reverse();
        result.Reverse();

        // Removing the empty lines at the end of the list
        RemoveWhiteSpaceItems();

        // Reversing again in order to recover the right list order.
        result.Reverse();

        return result;
    }
}
```

...and its usage:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "\t", " ", "    ", "a", "b", "\t", "         ", " " };

// The TrimList() extension method will return a new list without
// the empty items at the beginning and the end of the sample list!
List<string> trimmedList = list.TrimList();
```

Comment: This only removes the very first and the very last empty slot.

Comment: @poke And this is the goal of the OP, isn't it?

Comment: OP wants to remove empty *lines* (plural).

Comment: @poke It's not that clear. Maybe it's plural refering to the two possible empty lines (the first and the last one). Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: @poke What's confusing about `Remove empty lines at the beginning and at the end of a List`?

Comment: @poke In instance, what you will remove at the beginning and at the end if it's not the first and the last? what's the "middle" of the list...? What if the list has an odd count??

Comment: @DanielPeñalba What do you need to remove? The first and the last line, if these are empty or white space chars, or ANY "empty line" in the collection?

Comment: `[" ", " ", " ", " ", "A", "B", " ", "C", " ", "D", " ", " ", " "]` should trim to `["A", "B", " ", "C", " ", "D"]`. Remove all empty lines at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Altho I think removing only the first and last line of a list would be too simple a question, even for a very beginner in programming. Even if - why write an extension method for something that simple?

Answer (score 2):

This approach modifies the *original* `List<string>` instead of creating a new object with the desired property:

```
static void TrimEmptyLines(List<string> listToModify)
{
  if (listToModify == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

  int last = listToModify.FindLastIndex(HasContent);
  if (last == -1)
  {
    // no lines have content
    listToModify.Clear();
    return;
  }
  int count = listToModify.Count - last - 1;
  if (count > 0)
    listToModify.RemoveRange(last + 1, count);

  int first = listToModify.FindIndex(HasContent);
  if (first > 0)
    listToModify.RemoveRange(0, first);
}
```

In this code, `HasContent` is the method from the original question. One can use an anonymous function like a lambda instead, for the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what you need:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string> {"   \n\t", " ", "aaa", "  \t\n", "bb", "\n", " "};
IEnumerable<string> filtered = lines.SkipWhile(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace).Reverse().SkipWhile(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace).Reverse();
```

It reverses the list twice so it might not be the ideal solution if performance is a key.

Answer (score -1):

you can use  [isnullorwhitespace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorwhitespace)  to check this : See the below Example.

```
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.Add("         ");
        lines.Add("one");
        lines.Add("two");
        lines.Add("");
        lines.Add("");
        lines.Add("five");
        lines.Add("");
        lines.Add("       ");
        lines.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

Comment: I need to remove empty lines **only** at the beggining or at the end, this answer is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();
name.Add("              ");
name.Add("rajesh");
name.Add("raj");
name.Add("rakesh");
name.Add("              ");
for (int i = 0; i < name.Count(); i++)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(name[i])))
  {
    name.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you need `Convert.ToString(name[i])`?

Comment: @sil probably from the days before generics :D

Answer (score -2):

Regarding form your code, I guess that your lines neither contain whitespaces nor tabs, so you could replace the `foreach` with

```
if(line.Contains(' ') || line.Contains('\t'))
   return false;
return true;
```

Comment: There has been no specification about the lines contains whitespaces! From what I can see above these are the sole requirements!

Comment: @Hans Kesting: Please reconsider your downvote. This is exactly what the OP does in his class, only more efficient. So while not really answering the question it is not wrong per sé. I do think its wrong, but the error lies at the OP, not bash.d.

Comment: @bash.d - that `HasContent` checks whether the line contains any non-whitespace character. It doesn't care about extra whitespace in the content. It should catch empty lines and lines consisting of all whitespace. Both `"filled"` and `"with space"` should return true. A `"  "` or `""` should return false.

Answer (score -2):

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();
name.Add("              ");
name.Add("rajesh");
name.Add("raj");
name.Add("rakesh");
name.Add("              ");

name.RemoveAt(0);
name.RemoveAt(name.Count() - 1);
```

Comment: `Count` is not a method. This will also remove ANY string at the first or last index in the list, regardless of it being empty or not.

Comment: @DGibbs - `Count()` actually is an extension method in Linq, that can be used this way. But the rest of your comment is correct, though.